# Recognizing YouTube videos that can't be embedded in our app

Tags: video, iframe, youtube, hybrid

I've seen variations of this question about embedding YouTube videos in a website or mobile app. However, didn't find the angle to the answer that I was looking for. Appreciate any help with this!

**Problem Statement:** We are building a hybrid app and streaming selective YouTube videos embedded in an iFrame. Some YouTube videos don't play on the app due to restriction from the creator of that video - apparently some videos can't be played outside of YouTube.

The business users of our app will select the videos to embed, and so I want a simple way to tell them which videos to avoid selecting. Is there a simple way to identify if a video will not play when embedded in the iFrame?
Prefer if we can identify if a video will not be embeddable, from the YouTube web/app interface itself.